# HttpResponse which prompts for authentication headers

Tags: java, authentication, httpwebrequest

I'm creating some web requests using Jmeter, and trying to manually generate responses for them in a program I'm working on.

With the jmeter authentication manager I'm using it does not send authentication headers along with the original request. It requires a response to prompt the client to send along the authentication headers with the web request, but I can't figure out how to manually make the response that prompts for them. Can anyone tell me how such a response is formatted, or point out how I could figure it out? (I can play around with applications using Jmeter, Java, and Spring, but I don't know how to get Jmeter to show me the authentication prompt response.)

I tried formatting the response by making it a 401 "Unauthorized" response with the header: WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="lamerealm"
but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [HTTP basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) a response should look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="insert realm"
```

And the next request should look like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```